# Add marker for cities on a map using GeoRegionValuePlot

Tags: plotting, geography, geographics, marker

I would like to add some markers on some cities on a map (smaller or bigger depending on the values each city has)

```
vals={GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "Spain"], "SimplifiedArea"] -> 11.1268, 
         GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "China"], "SimplifiedArea"] -> 10.7984, 
         GeoVariant[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], "SimplifiedArea"] -> 
          10.5992}
GeoRegionValuePlot[vals, GeoRange -> {{-60, 90}, {-170, 190}}]
```

This gives the plot[image]

I would like to add now a Disk with radius 3 on New York, a disk with radius 2 on Madrid and a disk with radius 5 on Bejin.
Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine plots using `Show`.If you search docs you can easily find many examples. Note I used `GeoDisk` just to show you it exists. But you could also use `Disk` and `Epilog` for example. Or `GeoGraphics` instead of `GeoListPlot` etc. - there are many ways. Also consider [GeoBubbleChart](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoBubbleChart.html).

```
vals={
    GeoVariant[Entity["Country","Spain"],"SimplifiedArea"]->11.1268,
    GeoVariant[Entity["Country","China"],"SimplifiedArea"]->10.7984,
    GeoVariant[Entity["Country","UnitedStates"],"SimplifiedArea"]->10.5992};

cit = {
    GeoDisk[Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}], 
    Quantity[300, "Kilometers"]], 
    GeoDisk[Entity["City", {"Madrid", "Madrid", "Spain"}], 
    Quantity[200, "Kilometers"]], 
    GeoDisk[Entity["City", {"Beijing", "Beijing", "China"}], 
    Quantity[500, "Kilometers"]]};

pl1=GeoRegionValuePlot[vals,GeoRange->{{-60,90},{-170,190}}];
pl2=GeoListPlot[cit,GeoRange->{{-60,90},{-170,190}}];
Show[pl1, pl2]
```

[image]

Here example without `Show` just with `Epilog` and regular `Disk` for just NYC:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[vals, GeoRange -> {{-60, 90}, {-170, 190}}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, Opacity[0.5], Disk[Reverse[First[GeoPosition[
    Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]]]], 10]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. have a nice day

Comment: one think. The circle in the second method looks in a different perspective if I use different earth projections, i.e. , GeoProjection -> "WinkelTripel". do you know how to avoid this problem? thanks

Comment: @GiorgioColangelo but this is why I told you about GeoDisk?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach: use [`GeoBubbleChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoBubbleChart.html) to generate the disks and use the primitives as `Epilog`:

```
bubbles = {Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}] -> 3, 
   Entity["City", {"Madrid", "Madrid", "Spain"}] -> 2, 
   Entity["City", {"Beijing", "Beijing", "China"}] -> 5};

epilog = GeoBubbleChart[bubbles, 
    ColorFunction -> "GeographyHistogramGradient", 
    GeoBackground -> None][[1, 1]];

GeoRegionValuePlot[vals, GeoRange -> {{-60, 90}, {-170, 190}}, 
 Epilog -> {Opacity[.7], epilog}]
```

[image]